# Website links in Database to be accessed from my webpage

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am making an application in which the website links are to be stored in the oracle database and when I click from my HTML webpage it should take me to the concerned website .(No href link in my html  page).

I have stored website links in the Oracle database but I have no idea how to proceed further .The application has to be developed using servlets I guess.

Please help me out .

Answer (score 0):

May be you should provide a more detailed description of your entire requirement.From the details you have posted , this looks like a simple read-table-display-link process.If that is the case you can simply fetch the URLs using a select query (Query inside a servlet , stored procedure etc.) and write it on the page.

If you are looking at having a page that doesn't show the links as hyper links , then its a css job.